# Why IntelliJ IDEA prefers not to extend Composite when use GWT UiBinder?

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

Most examples in [UiBinder documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/uk-UA/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html) use base Composite class something like this:

```
public class UserDashboard extends Composite { 
    interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, UserDashboard> {}
    private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);
    public UserDashboard() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
}
```

At the same time IntelliJ IDEA always generates:

```
public class UserDashboard { 
    interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, UserDashboard> {}
    private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);
    public UserDashboard() {
        Widget widget = uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);
    }
}
```

So the question is why IntelliJ IDEA use second pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I whine about the Eclipse preference for the first version - making a Composite is one extra piece that really isn't all that helpful most of the time. Instead, just make `UserDashboard` implement `IsWidget`, and make the `asWidget()` method return the widget that your uibinder xml created.

Answer (score 0):

IDEA doesn't add 'extends Composite' because it isn't always required. However you can easily change this behavior: go to File | Settings | File Templates, open 'JavaEE' tab, select 'Google Web Toolkit' -> GwtUiBinder.java template and add 'extends Composite' to the template text. Also don't forget to add a required 'import' statement.